# Frames and Localization

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to ask if I use frames to make my layout, and I didn't use AutoLayout ,Is that difficult to make Localization? 
as I want to make two versions for my app  English version and Arabic one, but when I go through the steps to make my app support Arabic language the text fields when typing inside them don't begin from right instead they begin from left, Can anyone help me with this case?

Comment: Use autolayout. It can also take care of things like moving labels to the right of  field in RTL locales.

Comment: But it will take a lot of time to adjust the whole project, is there any possible solution don't make big changes on my code ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254462/uitextview-alignment-for-right-to-left-written-language

Comment: Thanks fir your comment i make their text alignment equals to nature and the problem is solved.